# How can I get iPads and IMac to reliably display html5 video?

Tags: ios, html5-video

Most threads relating to similar problems are years out of date. I'd be extremely grateful if anyone can shine a light here.
A small, 20 second video on my website is running into problems which seem inconsistent in the iOS environment.   I've searched every technical forum I can find and not been able to find a solution. The video works perfectly on any other O/S (Windows; Android; Amazon Fire; etc).

These are my test results with iOS devices:-

iPhone with iOS 13.6 - YES it runs ok.
iPad with iOS 9.3.6 - YES it runs (iPad too old to be updated further).
iPad Mini with iOS 13.6 - NO on any browser.
iMac with iOS 10.15.6 - Safari NO; Chrome YES Firefox YES.

This is my code (I'm using Bootstrap 4 framework for the site):-

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
            <video class="video-background" controls="true" controlsList="nodownload" playsinline>
                    <source src="videos/logoVid265.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    <source src="videos/logoVid.webm" type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
</div>
```

The .mp4 is H.265 encoded but I've also tried H.264 encoding with the same result.

Comment: If you can share a link to an example video which does not play it may be easier to help diagnose the issue

Comment: Sure, have a look at www.curlbrook.co.uk.  The video is about half way down on the right.

Answer (score 0):

The video in the web page in the link in the comments appears not to play on Safari on an iPAD running iOS 13.4.1, while playing fine on Safari on am MAC.

However, if you extract the video URL and paste it into a new tab on the same Browser on the same iPAD it plays properly, so the video itself is not the issue.

Digging deeper, it is actually the class in the containing div which is causing the issue:

```html
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
        <video controls="true" playsinline="true" class="">
          <!-- <video width="520" height="360" controls controlsList="nodownload"> -->
            <source src="videos/logoVid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="videos/logoVid.webm" type="video/webm;codecs=&quot;vp8, vorbis&quot;">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
</div>
```

If you remove this class the video will play on the original website on the same browser and device.

Going a little bit deeper again, if you just remove the 'overflow=hidden' or the 'position=relative" attribute in this style then the video will play.

You will likely want to investigate and experiment a bit further but it is possible the problem is simply that the video element or the controls are being masked by another layer on your page. Either way, the video itself is playing fine.

As a note, in case it is of interest, investigating this type of issue is much easier if you have access to a Mac you can connect your iOS device to. You can then use the web inspector in the Mac's Safari developer tools to inspect web pages on the the iOS device.

You do need to go into the settings on iOS and set this - at the time of writing this is at:

- iOS device -> settings -> safari - advanced -> 'Web Inspector' (enable this)

When you connect the iOS device to your Mac and open Safari you should see an option under the 'Develop' tab to connect to the device (you may need to enable developer options in Safari if you have not already):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  The class cannot be removed without making the video non-responsive.  i.e. it becomes necessary to scroll horizontally to see it and that isn't acceptable by current standards.   I don't have access to a Mac and my tests were carried out by distant friends.